# Using GROUP_CONCAT in Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have five tables in my database that I am working with. Everything works well till I start selecting states from the database using group concat.

These are my tables:

- main_jobs
- sub_jobs
- category
- state
- state_job_relationship

Snippet of my table creation

```
create table if not exists category (
    id int(3) not null auto_increment,
    parent int(5) not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    description text,
    slug varchar(255),
    level int (3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, slug));

create table if not exists state (
        id int(4) not null auto_increment,
        country_id int(11) not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (id))";

create table if not exists state_job_relationship (
        id int(4) not null auto_increment,
        state_id int(4) not null, FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state (id),
        job_id int(11) not null, FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES sub_jobs (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (id));

create table if not exists main_jobs (
            id int not null auto_increment, primary key(id),
            company_name varchar(255),
            job_title varchar(255));

create table if not exists sub_jobs (
            id int not null auto_increment, primary key(id),
            parent_id int(11) not null, FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES main_jobs (id),
            title varchar(255),
            description text not null,
            category int (3), FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES category (id)
            );
```

This is what I want to select:

The job titles from the sub jobs tables, with the corresponding company name and other details from main_jobs and category table.

All worked well till I needed to select the states each sub_job falls in this format: State1, State2, State3

```
select sub_jobs.id as kid, main_jobs.id as parentid, 
  company_name, sub_jobs.description, sub_jobs.title, 
  job_title, category.name as ind, 
  DATE_FORMAT($column_date,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as d, 
  (select group_concat(name seperator ', ') 
   from state_job_relationship, state 
   where job_id= kid 
     and state.id=state_job_relationship.state_id 
   group by state.id) states 
from sub_jobs, category, main_jobs 
where category.id=sub_jobs.category 
  and main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 
order by featured desc , $table.id desc 
limit 100;
```

Tried the query above but it displays this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'seperator ', ') from state_job_relationship, state where job_id= kid and state.i' at line 1

Please what am I not getting right?

Comment: Please format your question properly, especially the query you tried. It will also encourage more people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is because you are using the alais `kid` inside of the correlated subquery. You should replace the `kid` with the `sub_jobs.id`.

Also you have `seperator` spelled incorrectly.

So your code will be:

```
select s.id as kid, 
  m.id as parentid, 
  company_name, 
  s.description, 
  s.title, 
  job_title, 
  c.name as ind, 
  DATE_FORMAT($column_date,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as d, 
  (select group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') 
   from state_job_relationship
   inner join state 
     on state.id=state_job_relationship.state_id 
   where job_id= s.id 
   group by state.id) states 
from sub_jobs s
inner join category c
  on c.id=s.category 
inner join main_jobs m
  on m.id=s.parent_id 
order by featured desc , $table.id desc 
limit 100;
```

You will notice that I changed your syntax to use ANSI JOIN syntax and I am using aliasas for the tables.

The other suggestion that I have would be to use a subquery and join to the subquery:

```
select s.id as kid, 
  m.id as parentid, 
  company_name, 
  s.description, 
  s.title, 
  job_title, 
  c.name as ind, 
  DATE_FORMAT($column_date,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as d, 
  st.states 
from sub_jobs s
inner join category c
  on c.id=s.category 
inner join main_jobs m
  on m.id=s.parent_id 
left join
(
  select job_id, state.id, group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') states
  from state_job_relationship
  inner join state 
    on state.id=state_job_relationship.state_id 
  group by state.id, job_id
) st
  on st.job_id= s.id
order by featured desc , $table.id desc 
limit 100;
```

Comment: thank you so much for assisting me and formatting my question too. The query above shows this error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: thank you so so much! Its so so close! But it shows only a state per sub job even when i expect to have more than a state.

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: yeah thanks, was about doing so before i tried modifying the subquery: I grouped by only job_id ie. removed the state.id from the select and join and it works well now! Thanks... Kindly update... Thanks so so much

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu I am glad that you got it working, always happy to help! :)